# In RIDE if execution stopped abruptly message log, Log and Report not displayed from next run onwards

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

If in middle of execution, click on `Stop` button under `Run` tab in `RIDE` then from the next run onwards, it is not displayed `message log`, unable to open (it showed as disabled) `Log` and `Report` from RIDE.

How to resolve this.

Comment: This is a known bug on RIDE. (Actually they are two bugs, the disabled buttons, and missing the message log.).
Only restarting RIDE would restore normal functions.

Comment: Thanks for information helio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test is launching a process, like webdriver, then RIDE's output files may get locked by the stopped process. I have found that killing those processes would re-enable the Log and Report buttons on the next runs.

For example (before starting a test run), enter the command in a `cmd` or `sh`window:
On Windows:

```
taskkill /F /T /IM chromedriver.exe
```

On Linux:

```
killall chromedriver
```

Comment: Thanks for the details